# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException when specifying applicaiton/xml in Accept header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-serialization

Apologies, I didn't see a tag for java-noob.

I working with an existing restful api in Spring. I was tasked with adding a new api with a couple utility methods, each of which return a string. So far so good. All is working well.

I added a simple wrapper to return the string as an object and I'm able to build/deploy/test and I get back my response which looks like

```
{ id: "12345" }
```

If I specify the Accept header = `application/xml` I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Other methods in this package seem to serialize in both xml and json fine. I don't see any custom serialization code being used in the controller base and I don't know where it is handled (or if it is even related to serialization). *Can someone help me figure out where to start looking?*

Here is my [simplified] controller:

```
@Controller
public class UtilController extends ControllerBase
{

    @XmlRootElement(name="util_response")
    public static class UtilResponse extends APIResponseBase
    {
        private String id;

        @XmlElement(name="id")
        public String getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{pid}/util/output", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UtilResponse output(HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            @PathVariable("pid") int pid,
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required=true) String id) throws Exception
    {
            UtilResponse utilResponse = new UtilResponse();
            utilResponse.setId(id);
            return utilResponse;
    }
}
```

I also tried updating `@RequestMapping` and added `produces = "application/xml"` (yes, obviously having no clue what this really does), but that had zero effect.

Seriously, I'm really new about how all this java stuff "works" (.net dev by trade) and would love to understand more. I don't know what `Jackson` is, but I don't see references to it in our project and everything else seems to work so please no responses that say "Why don't you just use Jackson?" I also have deadlines so sometimes just getting it working takes precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please no responses that say "Why don't you just use Jackson?

Nobody would say that. Jackson is for `JSON` ;)

> produces = "application/xml" ..., but that had zero effect

`produces` restricts the handler method to the provided types. So `produces="application\xml"` makes the method unavailable for requests that expect `JSON`, e.g. It does not change the method's outcome.

Your description of the problem indicates that Spring is not able finding a way to serialize `UtilResponse` to `XML`. The most likely cause is that `JAXB2` is not present on the classpath. Spring uses that as default to create `XML`.

Comment: thanks, that got me on the right track. I added `<beans:value>....UtilController$UtilResponse</beans:value>` to servlet-context.xml and it worked magically!